# Node.js seems to be collecting private variables even though they're needed

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I have several modules which pull data from a database and store them in local memory.  I then have functions that pull data from the objects as different pages need them.  It works great, except once or twice a day on my staging server the objects are empty and I have to restart to server to fill the data in again.

I've removed some of the complexity here, but this is the idea, after several hours, roads is empty and getRoad always returns null;

```
var db = require('./db.js');

var roads = [];
db.query('select * from road', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    roads = rows;
});

module.exports.getRoad = function(id) {
    if (roads[id]) {
        return roads[id];
    }
    return null;
};
```

Update:

I'm adding db.js so you can see what's in there.  I've also put in a lot of logging around each one, so next time it fails I'll have more details.

```
var Pool = require('mysql-simple-pool');

var mysql_pool = new Pool(50, {
    host: process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database'
});

module.exports = mysql_pool;
```

Update:

Well, I could probably make a seperate question but it seems like the only things that are breaking are calls to the database.  So it's definitely not a problem with garbage collecting.  It seems some error or something with either mysql-simple-pool or something like that.  If anyone knows any reasons why mysql-simple-pool would stop responding after 12 or so hours I'd appreciate it :).

Comment: Something in the "complexity" is likely the problem -- I don't see anything that would be causing the issue you describe (unless the DB driver is calling the callback a second time hours later).

Comment: Interesting, i'll add a console.log into the db callback just to make sure.  This module isn't much more complex, but some of the others are more so.

Comment: Did you actually inspect ``roads`` to ascertain that it becomes empty or did you infer it from the behavior you observed? I can think of other reasons you'd get all ``null`` results. Like for instance if the code calling ``getRoad`` gets out of whack at some point and starts calling it with invalid ``id`` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this reduced code sample, the only scenario I can see is that your `db.query` callback function ends up getting invoked a second time several hours later, which would indicate some kind of problem in db.js.

Have you checked your logs for the `console.log(err)` output?

The data in `roads` would not be garbage collected since there *must* be a reachable reference to your module if you're calling `getRoad`; and if there is a reachable reference to the module itself, your locals would not be eligible for collection.

Also, a few tips: In a callback function, you should really only take action if there is no error.  In other words, add an **`else`**.

```
db.query('select * from road', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    else roads = rows;
});
```

If your callback is indeed getting called a second time (with an error), this would prevent `roads` from getting overwritten with nothing.

Finally, I would highly recommend making `getRoad` asynchronous.  This will give you flexibility in the future should you need to move to a more scalable caching solution (ie redis/memcahed/etc).  Something like:

```
module.exports.getRoad = function(id, cb) {
    if (roads[id]) { // this part could later be easily substituted for some
        cb(null, roads[id]); // other caching mechanism.
    } else {
        db.query('select * from road where id=?', [id], function(err, row) {
            if (err) cb(err);
            else if (row.length == 0) cb('Not found');
            else {
                roads[id] = row[0];
                cb(null, row[0]);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: haven't seen any error logs being output.  Ya, I've been considering refactoring the whole thing to use callbacks, I like the simplicity of not using them, but they simply might be required.

Comment: Im marking this as the answer because it is the proper way to write these in the first place and I hope it'll help others.  But my problem seems to be something in mysql-simple-pool